# javascript slow onload function

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm trying to call a javascript function onload.  The function would display a random div on every load.  It seems to pause for a few seconds before doing so.  My question is: Is this normal with the onload function or have I used it incorrectly?

Forgive my novice question.  I hope it's not to localized, but I appreciate your attention.  Here's a truncated sample of the html and javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);  
        window.onload = function() {
           if (randomNumber == 1) {
              document.getElementById("n1").style.display = "inline";
           }
           if (randomNumber == 2) {
              document.getElementById("n2").style.display = "inline";
           }
           if (randomNumber == 3) {
              document.getElementById("n3").style.display = "inline";
           }
        }
</script>

<body>

    <div id="n1" style="display:none">
        one
    </div>

    <div id="n2" style="display:none">
        two    
    </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong.. 
Checked console for anything?

Comment: `onload` is only fired when all assets (like images) are loaded. Do you maybe have any large images in your document that take a couple seconds?

Comment: Try adding the script at the end of the body instead of the head.

Comment: Thanks for your time!  In the invisible DIVs I load 21 images for a total of 173644 bytes.  Is that enough to cause a 3 or 4 second delay?

Comment: Depends on multiple factors, like your connection speed, what’s in cache already, etc. If you want to know for sure, then look at the loading process in your browser’s developer tools (f.e. in Chrome). // And if you want it to be executed before all external resources are loaded, then use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead of onload.

Comment: In addition to what CBroe said, it's also of interest from how many different sources the images are loaded from and how many requests you make.